# Random Forest Regressor: How to improve the implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I have a data set of stock and I am trying to predict "last" price of 5 days ahead. I have used RandomForestRegressor to predict the "last" price.
Here is the time series of the "last" price.
[image]

Here are the predicted price:

```
[ 56.45819  56.56159  57.05353  57.64981  57.85363]
```

And R square value score:

```
0.999883402515
```

Looking at the time series, last price has increased by the time, however, my predicted result doesn't imply this fact. The prediction is in the range of 50 - 60.

Here is the code:

```
class StockPricePrediction(object):

    trainData = pd.DataFrame()
    testData = pd.DataFrame()
    fullData = pd.DataFrame()
    features = []
    target_col = ''

    def __init__(self, priceTrainData, priceTestData, priceFullData, featuresOfInterest, target_column):

         #read csv data set
        self.trainData = pd.read_csv(priceTrainData)
        self.testData =  pd.read_csv(priceTestData)
        self.fullData = pd.read_csv(priceFullData)
        self.features = ['low', 'high', 'open', 'annualized_volatility', 'weekly_return','daily_average_volume_10','daily_average_volume_30','market_cap', 'monthly_return']

        self.target_col = 'last'

        self.trainData['Type'] = 'Train'
        self.testData['Type'] = 'Test'

def predict(self, numberOfPredictions):

            print("features")

            print(self.features)
            x_train = self.trainData[list(self.features)].values
            y_train = self.trainData[self.target_col].values
            x_test = self.testData[list(self.features)].values

            print("Train data:")
            rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 1000)
            rf.fit(x_train, y_train)
            status = rf.predict(x_test[0:numberOfPredictions])
            print("Train Data Predictions:")
            print(status)

            print("Train Data R square value score:")
            print(rf.score(x_train, y_train))
```

I want to know where am I going wrong ? And any suggestions about implementing new algorithm or how can I improve this algorithm.

Comment: This code may help you: https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Forecasting-Financial-Time-Series-Part-1

Comment: The link is related to classification problem, my problem is regression one, right?

Comment: I provided the link to give you an idea of how you might go about generating time-series features; there are some important differences between using non-time-series and time-series data in the context of ML model fitting and evaluation. My suggestions in no order would be to 1) start attempting to predict one day ahead instead of five; 2) use the _change_ in price as your target instead of the price itself; 3) put careful thought into generating quality features 4) Read others' blogs/reports about doing similar work and use their approaches as a model.